# My navbar will not go all the way across to the right

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have tried using display flex but for some reason when I do it completely ruins the pages, any idea what im doing wrong? After an entire week of trying to fix this im finally asking for help. Please keep in mind im new here please!

```
#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #d3d3d3;
  overflow: auto;
}

#navbar a {
  color: #d3d3d3;
}

#navbar .logo {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 50px; 
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;  
}

#navbar ul li {
  float: left;
}

#navbar ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover,
#navbar ul li a.current {
  background: #444;
  color: #ddd;
}
```

I would prefer to position it without flex if possible, as doing so seems to break the code. Please help I feel so lost and discouraged...

Comment: add HTML code as well